# lucene estimate index size, search time

Tags: lucene, performance-estimation

I search a way to estimate indexing time, index size, search time with lucene library.

I have some number for 500 files and i would like to estimate value for 5000 document.

I search on the web and i don't found any good way to estimate theses number.

Comment: Put 5000 sample documents in the index and try it.  Don't guess; experiment and measure.

Comment: it's ok when you have very few documents.... but if i want to estimate for 2 billions documents, i can't really use this approach...

Comment: If you have 2 billion documents, do you really want to base your resource allocation on a guess?  Honestly, that's where load testing (not load guessing) is most critical.

Comment: surely not, but having a idea before begining it's just normal

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends hugely on what you put into the index. Obviously, if you store full field content, then you can expect at least linear growth, with the factor within an order of magnitude from 1. If you only index the terms, you will need much less space, but at the same time the estimate will get much more difficult. The number of unique index terms is a very important factor, for example. This will probably start levelling off at some number that depends highly on the details of your content. All in all, in such a case measurement is probably your only reliable method.